# Deny Access to Item for Group of Users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, permissions

My client has a requirement to deny access to items in a SharePoint list to a particular group of users.    By default, the list is shared with "Whole Company", but if an item is marked "No Contractor" then it should be available to the whole company, except for members of the "Contractors" group.

The best solution I’ve come up with is two have two groups ("Whole Company" and "Whole Company Excluding Contractors") and have a workflow that replaces the item permissions if the item is marked “No Contractor".

The problem is I have to do this across every list - I'm not keen on having to create this workflow on every single list in SharePoint.

Is there a way to do this with permissions natively in SharePoint without the need for a workflow on every list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom timer job to loop all items which are marked "No Contractor",then batch update item permissions for these items.

[SharePoint Batch Updating List Items Programatically](http://sharepointcore.blogspot.com/2011/12/sharepoint-batch-updating-list-items.html)

[How to Create Timer Job in SharePoint 2013](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8e86c/how-to-create-timer-job-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Answer (score 1):

You may use **Reusable Workflow** for your requirement.

SharePoint reusable workflow is associated with Content Type. This workflow requires extra customization to associate it with a list or library. The benefit is that you can save the SharePoint reusable workflow as a template and apply to different lists and libraries that support the same content type. In other words, you can create a workflow action based on a columns set and start for all lists which have the same column (content type)

**Ref:** https://blog.virtosoftware.com/how-to-create-sharepoint-2013-reusable-workflow/